# How to use column index in dcast

Tags: r, data.table

I want to use column index in dcast in data.table:

```
dcast(setDT(x),rowid(X__9) ~ X__9,value.var = "count")
```

Above works fine,but column name `X__9` is dynamic it may change to `X__7` or `X__8`. How can we pass column index `1` to dcast so that every time it will work irrespective of dynamic column names. I tried:

```
dcast(setDT(x),rowid(names(.)[1]) ~ names(.)[1],value.var = "count")
```

But it does not work.